# Resize JComponent for file export

Tags: java, swing, resize, bufferedimage, jcomponent

I have a JPanel upon which I draw a number of custom-written JComponents using the usual 'paintComponent(Graphics g)' method.  I use a JLayeredPane to control the display order of the custom components, as follows:

```
public Class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    private JComponent component1;
    private JComponent component2;

    public MyPanel() {
        super();
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        component1 = new CustomComponent1();
        layeredPane.add (component1, new Integer(0));

        component2 = new CustomComponent2();
        layeredPane.add (component2, new Integer(1));

        add (layeredPane);
    }

    public void resizePanel(Graphics g, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        component1.setBounds (f(x), f(y), f(newWidth), f(newHeight));
        component2.setBounds (f(x), f(y), f(newWidth), f(newHeight));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if ((getWidth() != oldWidth) || (getHeight() != oldHeight)) {
            oldWidth = getWidth();
            oldHeight = getHeight();
            resizePanel (g, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
```

Now, I would like to export this panel to a JPEG file, but with a different size.  When I use the following code, it successfully creates/exports a JPEG file of the desired size, but it also updates my screen image version of the panel to the new size!  Yikes!

```
public void export(File file, int width, int height)
    throws IOException
{
    BufferedImage scaledImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = scaledImage.createGraphics();
    resizePanel (g2, width, height);
    super.paintComponent (g2);

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
        encoder.encode(scaledImage);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IOException ("Unable to export chart to ("
                  + file.getAbsolutePath() + "): " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

How can I 'draw' an image suitable for exporting, but not actually cause this new image to be displayed?

Thanks!

---

Well, I'm back to this problem again.....

The scene I'm painting includes some text and now the end user wants the graph exported in a 'portrait' aspect ratio. Since I'm not repainting the scene in the new dimensions but just scaling the image, this causes the text to be seriously squashed horizontally.

Anyway around that?

Comment: Cross posted: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5427732&tstart=0

Comment: Which correctly suggests using javax.imageio: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't resize your panel at all; just create a [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) that's the panel's current size and paint it. Once you've got the snapshot, scale it to your desired dimensions in a second [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) using [`drawImage()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) or [`AffineTransformOp`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html).

Addendum: One advantage of [`AffineTransformOp`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html) is control over rotation, interpolation, scale and aspect ratio:

```
BufferedImage image = ...
int w = image.getWidth();
int h = image.getHeight();
AffineTransform scaleTransform = new AffineTransform();
// last-in-first-applied: rotate, scale
scaleTransform.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
scaleTransform.rotate(Math.PI / 2, w / 2, h / 2);
AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(
        scaleTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
BufferedImage new = scaleOp.filter(image, null);
```

Comment: Well, this method looks slightly better than doing the 'g2.scale()' n redrawing the components, but the text is still horizontally scrunched a bit.

I'll go with this method for now.

Thanks again. R

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a second excellent solution.  The final solution I have looks like the following:

```
public void export(File file, int width, int height)
throws IOException
{
    BufferedImage scaledImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = scaledImage.createGraphics();
    g2.scale(((double) width)/((double)getWidth()), ((double) height)/((double)getHeight()));
    paintComponents(g2);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(scaledImage, "jpg", file);            
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IOException ("Unable to export chart to ("
         + file.getAbsolutePath() + "): " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way I could get everything to look OK (e.g., no scaling of text after it's been rasterized) is to draw the image on a new graphics context using the new size.  Here's my new 'export()' method.

```
    public void export(File file, final int width, final int height)
    throws IOException
{

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    final Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();

    //  Must wait for the bloody image to be drawn as Swing 'paint()' methods
    //  merely schedule painting events.  The 'draw()' below may not complete
    //  the painting process before the 'write()' of the image is performed.

    //  thus, we wait....

    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                draw (g2, new Rectangle (0, 0, width, height));
            }
        });
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException ("Unable to export chart to ("
                + file.getAbsolutePath() + "): " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

The 'draw()' method called above calls the 'setbounds()' method on all of my sub-components which draws them onto the new buffered image.  A bit of work, but the result is exactly what I need.