# Java Creating colored circle in XWPFDocument using Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm trying to add a 2 colored circle to my document using Apache POI 5.2.3.
The circle should look like this:[image]

So far the closest I got to adding a shape to the document was using the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53857670/10964215) but it adds a different shape than a circle. I tried following the rules explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70607928/10964215) but didn't manage to make a circle. The other issue I have is that I need my circle to have 2 colors, one in each half of the circle and but I don't know how to color the shape in more than 1 color.
How can I add a 2 colored circle to the doc?

### Some workaround

1 workaround I found and I rather not use it unless it's the last result, is generating an image with 2 colors and then adding the image to the doc. I rather not use it because I want to be able to edit the shape in the final Document generated.
the code for image generation:

```
public void drawCircle(XWPFDocument document) {
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();

    try {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        Color color1 = Color.RED;
        Color color2 = Color.BLUE;
        GradientPaint gp1 = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, 0, 20, color2);
        GradientPaint gp2 = new GradientPaint(0, 20, color2, 0, 40, color1);
        g2d.setColor(color1);
        g2d.fill(new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, 100, 100, 90, 180, Arc2D.PIE));
        g2d.setColor(color2);
        g2d.fill(new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, 100, 100, -90, 180, Arc2D.PIE));
        g2d.dispose();

        File file = new File("circle.png");
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        String imageId = document.addPictureData(inputStream, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);

        run.addPicture(new FileInputStream(file),
                XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG,
                "circle.png",
                Units.toEMU(30),
                Units.toEMU(30));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also consider `AffineTransformOp` to rotate and scale, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246484/230513).

Comment: How would you create that kind of shape using Microsoft Word GUI?